# Find and Replace all occurrences of a phrase in a json string using capturing groups

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a stringified JSON which looks like this:

...

```
"message":null,"elementId:["xyz1","l9ie","xyz1"]}}]}], "startIndex":"1", 
"transitionTime":"3","sourceId":"xyz1","isLocked":false,"autoplay":false
,"mutevideo":false,"loopvideo":false,"soundonhover":false,"videoCntrlVisibility":0,
...,"elementId:["dgff","xyz1","jkh90"]}}]}]
```

... it goes on.

The part I need to work on is the value of the `elementId` key. (The 2nd key in the first line, and the last key).

This key is present in multiple places in the JSON string. The value of this key is an array containing 4-character ids.

I need to replace one of these ids with a new one.

The kernel of the idea is something like:

```
var elemId = 'xyz1' // for instance
var regex = new RegExp(elemId, 'g');
var newString = jsonString.replace(regex, newRandomId);
jsonString = newString;
```

There are a couple of problems with this approach. The regex will match the id anywhere in the JSON. I need a regex which only matches it inside the elementId array; and nowhere else.

I'm trying to use a capturing group to match just the occurrences I need, but I can't quite crack it. I have:

```
/.*elementId":\[".*(xyz1).*"\]}}]/
```

But this doesn't match the 1st occurence of 'xyz1 in the array.

So, **firstly, I need a regex which can match all the 'xyz1's inside elementId; but nowhere else**. The sequence of square and curly brackets after elementId ends doesn't change anywhere in the string, if that helps.

Secondly, even if I have a capturing group that works, `string.replace` doesn't act as expected. Instead of replacing just the match inside the capturing group, it replaces the whole match.

So, my second requirement is **replacing only the captured groups, not the whole match.**

What a need is a piece of js code which will replace my 'xyz1's where needed and return the following string (assuming the newRandomId is 'abcd'):

```
"message":null,"elementId:["abcd","l9ie","abcd"]}}]}], "startIndex":"1", 
"transitionTime":"3","sourceId":"xyz1","isLocked":false,"autoplay":false
,"mutevideo":false,"loopvideo":false,"soundonhover":false,"videoCntrlVisibility":0,
...,"elementId:["dgff","abcd","jkh9"]}}]}]
```

Note that the value of 'sourceId' is unaffected.

EDIT: I have to work with the JSON. I can't parse it and work with the object since I don't know all the places the old id might be in the object and looping through it multiple times (for multiple elements) would be time-consuming

Comment: But... why not just parse the JSON and work on the object ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I have to replace multiple ids with random new ids. And I don't know all the places the old ids might be. The json is huge, and looping through the entire object mutiple times will take a lot of time

Comment: Not all ids here are 4 chars long. Is that normal ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: No. Proobably a type. I've edited it. They're all 4 chars, composed of digits and uppercase or lowercase letters.

Comment: Be careful to your tests. It should also be `"elementId":["abcd","l9ie","abcd"]` instead of  `"elementId:["abcd","l9ie","abcd"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't just parse and change the JS object, you could use 2 regexes: one to extract the array and the one to change the desired ids inside:

```
var output = input.replace(/("elementId"\s*:\s*\[)((?:".{4}",?)*)(\])/g, function(_,start,content,end){
  return start + content.replace(/"xyz1"/g, '"rand"') + end;
});
```

The arguments `_`, `start`, `content`, `end` are produced as result of the regex ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)):

- `_` is the whole matched string (from `"elementId:\[` to `]`). I choose this name because it's an old convention for arguments you don't use
- `start` is the first group (`"elementId:\[`)
- `content` is the second captured group, that is the internal part of the array
- `end` id the third group, `]`

Using the groups instead of hardcoding the `start` and `end` parts in the returned string serves two purposes

- avoid duplication (DRY principle)
- make it possible  to have variable strings (for example in my regex I accept optional spaces after the `:`)

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML.trim();
var output = input.replace(/("elementId":\s*\[)((?:".{4}",?)*)(\])/g, function(_,start,content,end){
  return start + content.replace(/"xyz1"/g, '"rand"') + end;
});

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
Input:
<pre id=input>
"message":null,"elementId":["xyz1","l9ie","xyz1"]}}]}], "startIndex":"1", 
"transitionTime":"3","sourceId":"xyz1","isLocked":false,"autoplay":false
,"mutevideo":false,"loopvideo":false,"soundonhover":false,"videoCntrlVisibility":0,
...,"elementId":["dgff","xyz1","jkh9"]}}]}]
</pre>
Output:
<pre id=output>
</pre>
```

Notes:

- it would be easy to do the whole operation in one regex if they weren't repetition of the searched id in one array. But the present structure makes it easy to handle several ids to replace at once.
- I use non captured groups `(?:...)` in order to unclutter the arguments passed to the external replacing callback

Comment: Thanks for answering. but I don't quite get the answer. Also, a quick check of the regex after `input.replace` shows that my id's are not getting matched. But I like your idea of using a function as the 2nd arg of replace.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction Did you try the snippet ? It works

Comment: You're right. It works perfectly on the snippet. For some reason, I can't get it to work in my codebase. I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help. If you could explain what the arguments in the replace function are for(_, start, content, end), that'd be very helpful for me.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction I added some explanations. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Much better now. Thanks a ton. Didn't know that passing regex produces these args.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction A possible reason of your problem using this code is that you're missing a quote in your example after elementId. I'll change the snippet for a more correct JSON

Comment: Got it to work. Thanks. And you're right about the typo (my work keyboard is shitty), but the problem was something else. You had my upvote. Now, you have my accept.

Comment: Hi again. Just wondering if you could provide a little more help. Supposing I use this code inside a function called myFunction. myFunction has an object called myObject. I need to access myObject from inside the function in this solution (in order to determine the correct value of 'rand'). I can't seem to access anything in myFunction when I'm inside this fn. Is there a way to do that? Or a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: There should be no problem. Any variable or argument of the external function call is visible inside the internal one. You should ask another question on that specific problem after having made a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).